# Calculate repeater items which is in user control and display it in literal which is in page?

Tags: asp.net, events, delegates

I've a scenario where I want to calculate the no of records in repeater which is in user control and display the count in a literal which is in page(ex default.aspx). How can I achieve this ? I don't wanna use public properties....i want to do it by creating my own custom event.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sumit Arora

Comment: How can I  get the value of a property which is in user control on page load of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in the user control:

```
public int NumberOfRecords { get { return myRepeater.Items.Count; } }
```

Then, in the Page_Load:

```
countLabel.Text = string.Format("Number of records: {0}", myUserControl.NumberOfRecords);
```

Comment: Well the problem in  this case is that the page load of Page will be called first and then the page load of user control will be called....so how can I get the value of the property in the page load of the page?It won't give me any record.

Comment: You could force the databind in the page_load, before calling the property. Or put the countLabel.Text = ... in the Page_OnPreRender.